# Multiple PhD applications

Tags: phd, advisor, funding

I'm a student from India who wants to do PhD(in math) in Germany in September 2019. The first thing I did was mail a couple of supervisors who I thought would be interested to work with me. Among them, I have received two positive responses. Now, the next step is to apply for DAAD scholarship. As far as I'm aware, I can only send one application for the scholarship. Does this mean that I will have to choose one of the supervisors now and hope that I get the scholarship?

Does this also mean that I cannot apply to multiple places in Germany to increase my chances of getting a position?

Answer (score 3):

This is highly specific and might require reading between the lines. Your best and simplest course of action is to contact the admins in the funding body and simply ask them.